# Pushwoosh custom data escapes forward slashes

Tags: json, api, pushwoosh

I'm trying to push some custom data using 'data' tag from the API. Here is my message request:

```
{"request":{"application":"app-code","notifications":[{"content":"Constantly talking isn't necessarily communicating.","send_date":"now","data":{"url":"appName://page?id=1827"},"devices":["pushtoken1","pushtoken2"]}],"auth":"auth-key"}}
```

The above 'url' works fine when I send a Push Notification from CP,but it gets converted into following {"url":"appName:\/\/page?id=1827"} when sending from an API. which eventually makes the user to land on the app home page instead.

Any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting the issue! This has been fixed (will be available LIVE in about an hour).